# How to write a raw data in physical memory to NVMe ssd using kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, nvme

I am currently looking for an implementation which directly writes data in kernel dma buffer into NVMe SSD with good data speed. I have looked in SPDK library which operates in user space.

Is there any way to directly map the DMA memory in kernel space to nvme SSD m2 dma buffer?